# Javascript replace( ) function running more than once on the same image

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, replace

I'm running a Javascript replace function to replace standard images with `class="replace-2x"`on my jQuery Mobile site with Retina-quality images if the user is on a mobile device with Retina display. For example, on a Retina device, `logo.png` will be replaced with `logo@2x.png`. The JS function is here:

```
function highdpi_init() {
    $(".replace-2x").each(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).attr("src", src.replace(".png", "@2x.png").replace(".jpg", "@2x.jpg"));

    });
}

$(".page").live('pageinit',function(event){
    highdpi_init();
});
```

I'm now running into an issue where the replace function is running more than once. So for example, it replaces `logo.png` with `logo@2x.png` as the page is loading, but then as the page continues to load, it KEEPS replacing `.png` with `@2x.png` in the img src over and over so that the image tag ends up looking like this:

```
<img src="mobile/images/logo@2x@2x@2x@2x@2x@2x@2x@2x@2x@2x@2x.png" class="replace-2x" alt="logo" width="200">
```

How can I prevent this from replacing on a single img element more than once? Keep in mind, I will have multiple images on the same page, so the function will need to apply to all images, but only one time each.

Comment: The `pageinit` event appears to be firing more than once. How about using `.one('pageinit')` instead of `.live('pageinit')`?

Comment: Will this allow the function to still run for all the images on the page? When I used `.one` the function doesn't seem to fire..?

Comment: Not if new images were added after the first time the 'pageinit' event was fired

Comment: Can you use the `.one` on the function itself rather than taking out the `.live` ? Or is there another way?

Comment: How do you determine if the mobile has a retina display? I would consider checking when you render the page and setting the correct file path then. Doesn't seem like you need to mess around with javascript for something like this

Comment: I define the `replace-2x` class in a special stylesheet that is only loaded if the device is high-pixel-density compatable (pixel ratio of 2)

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/css/highdpi.css"/>`

Comment: @adamdehaven You could improve your code and remove the JS by making your images use background images. Then your stylesheet could determine what to use as the `background-image: url()` property

Comment: Question: in the JS code listed above, on the line ` $(".replace-2x").each(function () {` how could I modify this to say, "If it has the class, and `.css('font-size') == "1px"`?

Comment: You could add a check inside of the handler itself `function(){if ($(this).css('font-size') == '1px') {return}}`

Comment: So where would I place this in the code?

Comment: As the first line in your function that gets passed to `$('.replace-2x' ).each(function(){ // check goes here})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is surely that your 'pageinit' event is being called more than once. You can either follow MДΓΓ БДLL's idea (which won't work if images are dynamically added) or you can make your handler smarter so that it doesn't replace the src if it already was replaced

```
function highdpi_init() {
    $(".replace-2x").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var src = $this.attr("src");
        $this.attr("src", src.replace(".png", "@2x.png").replace(".jpg", "@2x.jpg"));
        // Remove the class so it doesn't replace it again
        $this.removeClass('replace-2x')

    });
}
```

You don't need JS for this, you could do it in CSS only.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/css/highdpi.css"/>
```

You could make your images look like

```
<img src="transparent.gif" class="logo-a" alt="logo" width="200" />
```

And in `highdpi.css` you could do

```
img.logo-a {
   background-image: url('file@2x.png') 
}
```

And in `lowdpi.css`

```
img.logo-a {
   background-image: url('file.png') 
}
```

Comment: Question: in the JS code listed above, on the line ` $(".replace-2x").each(function () {` how could I modify this to say, "If it has the class, and the class declares that  `.css('font-size') == "1px"`?

Comment: @adamdehaven Did you just ask the same question twice? I answered it up there, be sure to mark the question as answered. And also be sure to test the solution I posted that doesn't require JS, just CSS

Comment: I appreciate the CSS-only solution, but I don't want to have to code everything twice. I want to be able to use JS so that I can include the image on the page once without having to modify a separate css file every time I insert an image onto the site

Answer (score 0):

Using .one() should work since it is just a binding and if you are using Jquery Mobile the way that is suggested it will be just fine. That is unless you are passing back the html from the server. In which case it would be a good idea to add an extra condition to make sure that the src doesn't already have @2x.png before replacing.

Answer (score 0):

There is disappointingly little documentation on pageinit on the offical jQuery Mobile docs.  So I'm going to speculate here.  It looks like `pageinit` is used to fire events for when a specific DOM element has finished loading, since it may not have been loaded on the initial page load (deferred until needed).  That being said, it may be that adding/altering images to the DOM element in question fires the pageinit again.  Could you tag each updated image with something that says, 'hey, I've already been updated to 2x'?  Something such as

```
$.data(targetimg, 'retinafied', true);
```

And then check for that value before replacing the src?

Comment: This adds a new state variable, just removing the `.replace=2x` is simpler